# Mascara com ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Estou fazendo um trabalho para a faculdade com *asp.net core MVC*, e estou usando o *entity* para gerar as *view* e as consultas no BD. Preciso colocar mascara nos campos como por exemplo CNPJ. Eu consegui pesquisando no Google como colocar mascara, mas quando tento criar um registro, ele da erro por causa da máscara.

Queria saber como faço para tirar a mascara e enviar para o BD somente os números.

**View:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RazaoSocial" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="RazaoSocial" placeholder="Razão Social" class="form-control" , />
            <span asp-validation-for="RazaoSocial" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="NomeFantasia" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="NomeFantasia" placeholder="Nome Fantasia" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="NomeFantasia" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Cnpj" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Cnpj" placeholder="Somente Numero" data-mask="00.000.000/0000-00" data-mask-reverser="false" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Cnpj" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Ie" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Ie" placeholder="Somente Numero" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Ie" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Avançar" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("EmpresaId,RazaoSocial,NomeFantasia,Cnpj,Ie")] Empresa empresa)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            _context.Add(empresa);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(empresa);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode limpar o campo do CNPJ removendo os caracteres especiais antes de enviar para o banco de dados. Para isso, crie um método para tal. Adicione o seguinte método no seu `Controller`:

```
private string ClearCNPJ(string cnpj)
{
   return cnpj.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty);
}
```

Para utilizar, dentro do método `Create`, coloque da seguinte forma:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    empresa.Cnpj = ClearCNPJ(empresa.Cnpj);
    _context.Add(empresa);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

return View(empresa);
```

Ou pode ainda criar um método de extensão que pode ser usado em qualquer `string` criada. Crie uma classe `static` igual ao exemplo abaixo.

```
 public static class StringExtensions
 {
     public static string ClearCNPJ(this string value)
     {
          return value.Replace(".", string.Empty).Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("/", string.Empty);
     }
 }
```

Na classe que irá utilizar (`Controller` no seu caso), coloque a diretiva `using`:

```
using seuprojeto.StringExtensions;
```

E para utilizar, dentro do método `Create`, coloque da seguinte forma:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    empresa.Cnpj = empresa.Cnpj.ClearCNPJ();
    _context.Add(empresa);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

return View(empresa);
```

Comment: E como eu faço para receber o cnpj, pois meu controller foi criado automaticamente pelo entity e esta assim como mostrado na pergunta(editei agora).

Comment: @AndréLuizdaSilva Você utiliza o objeto "empresa" dentro do método Create. Alterei a resposta com o que deve usar. Não esqueça de criar um dos métodos que apresentei.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou certinho.